Manhwa about a green eyed, blonde haired female lead
Female lead has blonde hair and green eyes. She is the daughter of a powerful noble. Her mother is locked away in a tower by her father which forces the FL to do his bidding. The main lead I belive is either a powerful noble or king. The ML and the FL father are rivals. The FL father plots a revolution but ends up being killed by the FL.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Does this contain any science fiction or fantasy elements that would make it on-topic here?

Wished You Were Dead? Maybe?

King Karloi of Croisen finds himself at odds with his position in life. His wife’s father, Duke Deluah, is angling for the throne, and as an outsider to the family, Karloi fears for his position. His frustrations have affected his marriage, though he finds himself questioning his cold approach to his wife, Evonne. He may no longer recognize her, but Evonne saved his life long ago, and was his first love. This is but one of many secrets Evonne bears the weight of, having fallen victim to a curse that prevents her from telling any secrets...

The description is very vague, but it could also fit this manhwa. In this one, the father used dark magic on the female lead. :D Hopefully it helps.
